# Adams Variable Step-Size Predictor-Corrector python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I don't know to use initial values with Rk4 and use variable step size with h. My initial values is in q. My initial conditions are: a= 0, b= 12, y0=1, tol= 1e-5, hmax= 1,  and hmin= 0.1

```
def P_C_A1( m, a, b, y0, tol, hmax, hmin ): #m is a function

i=3

h = hmax   
t = a +3*h
T = np.array( [t] )


q= rk4_4(m,y0,4,h)[1][:4].tolist()  #Initial values RK4
k1= m(q[3],0+3*h)
k2= m(q[2],0+2*h)
k3= m(q[1],+h)
k4= m(q[0],0)  
while t and i< b:
    
    if t + h > b:
      h = b - t
                                                          
    y= q[i] 
    #Corrector  
    y= q[i] + h/24*( 55*m(q[i],t) -59*m(q[i-1],t-h)+ 37*m(q[i-2],t-2*h) -9*m(q[i-3],t-3*h))
      
    k0 = m(y, t+h)
    #Predictor    
    w = q[i] + h*(9*m(y, t+h)+19*m(q[i],t)-5*m(q[i-1],t-h)+m(q[i-2],t-2*h))/24
    
    r = (19/270*h)*abs( w-y )  # error
    
    if len( np.shape( r ) ) > 0:
      r = max(r)
    if r <= tol:
        
        t = t + h
        i= i +1
           

        
        
     
        q.append(w)
        
        T = np.append( T, t )
        
    z = (tol/(2*r))**0.25 #  
    
    if (z <= 0.1):
      h = 0.1*h   # ( big error ) 0.1 is min value for z
    elif (z >= 1):
      h = 1.*h    #1 is max value for z
    else:
      h = z*h     #scalar h a z*h, paso ideal ( 0.1 < z < 1)
    
    if   (h > hmax): h = hmax  # Not allowed values greater hmax
    elif (h < hmin): 
        print('(h not allowed.')
        break
    
return ( T, q )

k= 0.0009906
def m(x,t):
  return k*x*(1000-x)
P_C_A1( m, 0, 12, 0, 1e-5, 1,0.1 )
```

Ouput:
h not allowed

So How can I change h and use my range of values for h?. I probably have errors in my code but I don't see them.

Comment: You can't, at least not in a simple way like for one-step methods. The AB and AM methods are constructed for constant step size. You would need to restart for the new step size either via interpolation in the past or via bootstrap for an initial segment. For truly variable step size you would need to compute the method coefficients in each step.

Comment: How can i do this with Newton method of interpolation?Could you explain me please.